# MS-SQL: How to generate fragment of the script to create view only on certain machine?

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax, scripting

**Context:** Production environment defines views to access data from another database. Testing environment needs to simulate that by views with the same name and different definition. Instalation script is generated as one text file. I am using MS-SQL Server 2016. The views were defined by someone else.

**Details:** The `CREATE VIEW dbo.view_xyz ...` syntax *must be the oly statement in the batch*, and--to re-create the view--I need to drop the older version of the view first. Because of that, my installers usually define it like this (if the views are defined by myself):

```sql
IF (OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.view_xyz', 'V') IS NOT NULL)
    DROP VIEW dbo.view_xyz
GO

CREATE VIEW dbo.view_xyz  AS
    SELECT ... [snip usual definition]
```

Here, after the `GO`, the requirement is fulfilled.

I want to use *the same installation script* at both production and testing machine. So, I want to create the view conditionally (that is *do nothing at the production machine* and *drop and create again* on testing machine). I can test the SQL instance to recognize the situation. I would like to do something like:

```sql
IF @@servername = 'TESTMACHINE\SQL2016NAMEDINSTANCE'
    IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.view_xyz', 'V') IS NOT NULL
        DROP VIEW dbo.view_xyz

-- the GO cannot be here

    CREATE VIEW dbo.view_xyz  AS
        SELECT * FROM theTableThatSimulatesTheContentOfTheProductionView
END
```

However, I cannot place the `GO` separator in front of the `CREATE VIEW ...`. The `CREATE VIEW ...` must not be in the `IF ...` body.

How to solve that?

Comment: One method would be to execute the `CREATE`/`ALTER` script in a separate scope, using `sys.sp_executesql`.

Comment: @Larnu: Good point! Please, formulate it as the answer and I will accept it.